# MegaRAID: what does yellow "r" on drive icon mean?

Tags: raid, ubuntu-14.04, hardware-raid, megaraid, megaraid-storage-manager

One of our drives has a yellow square overlay on its icon in the Drives list.  I think there's an "r" in the square (see image).  I can't find this described in the MegaRAID manual anywhere.

When I view drive properties while flipping back and forth between this drive and the others, the only difference I notice is that this one has "Full Disk Encryption capable: yes" whereas the others are "no".

Anyone know what this means?

[image: Yellow "r" icon in context]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not so much a yellow square as it is an oddly drawn open yellow padlock.

It means exactly what you said in your question - that encryption is possible but the drive is not encrypted (thus "unlocked").